# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I followed the steps exactly as in this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-python-hello-world-example-using-eclipse/

When i try to run in i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in 
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1033, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1026, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 752, in start
    options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 795, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(config_path, app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 123, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 391, in _parse_configuration
    with open(configuration_path) as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\x93D:\\Helloworld/src\x93'
```

I followed the steps exactly.

helloworld.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

app.yaml:

```
application: feebe-1096
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I literaly just installed eclipse, PyDev plugin and the app engine SDK just before trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the \x93 in the error message: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '\x93D:\Helloworld/src\x93'

\x93 is the code of the " symbol. You (very likely) entered a string with "-s where there should be none. Please check your configurations. And remove the "-s

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I had put quotes around the path directory in the arguments.